# who is the best theme load time speed in WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, performance, themes

friend i have junior developer and i have create site but site home page is load time is 15 second. how can use i use best theme in my site plz ask best theme...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here are the 11 ways to speed up WordPress:**

- Choose a better web hosting provider
- Use a lightweight WordPress theme/framework
- Reduce image sizes
- Minify JS and CSS files
- Use advanced caching mechanisms with a caching plugin
- Use a CDN
- Enable GZIP compression
- Cleanup WordPress database
- Deactivate or uninstall plugins
- Keep external scripts to a minimum
- Disable pingbacks and trackbacks

Answer (score 0):

you can use wp rocket plugin.this plugin working any theme